# How to check number field is null in Android

Tags: java, android

```
public void saveData(View view) {
        name = txtName.getText().toString();
        age = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText().toString());
```

"Here I tried with --> age==0 , age=="" but it didn't work.

```
 if(name.trim().equals("") && age==null)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to accomplish

Comment: or getting some error?

Comment: just want to validate the number field. because if I didn't give any data and click the submit button, app will crash.

Comment: yes it definitely cashes because Integer cannot parse an empty string

Comment: name.text.toString()==""

Answer (score 1):

&& or || can not be applied to `int`

You can use

```
String name = txtName.getText().toString();
String age = txtAge.getText().toString();


if (name.equals("") && age.equals("")) {


}else {


}
```

Or you can simple use `TextUtils` to check empty

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && TextUtils.isEmpty(age)){


}else {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt` cannot parse an empty string or string with spaces or alphabetical characters. see for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer#parseInt(java.lang.String)

put try-catch around integer parsing

```
try{
    age = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText().toString());
} catch(Exception e){
    age = 0
    //or set age = null
}
```